# Auto scrolling back issue with scroll on a div for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-8.1

So, I'm developing a app for Windows Phone 8.1 and Im having an issue when trying to use scrollable divs (javascript). Using the emulator to test the app, when I scroll down and let go the mouse button, it automatically scrolls back up, making it impossible to click on lower items. Note that Im using overflow:scroll on the div. I also use jquery mobile.

So here is my code:

```
        <div data-dom-cache="false" data-role="page" id="index">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">

            <h1 style="padding-top:0.2em;padding-bottom:0;border:0"><img alt="ss" src="img/logoHeader.jpg" /></h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" id="wrapper" style="padding:0.5em; overflow:scroll;" >

            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">

                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#USA" data-transition="slide">
                        <img src="img/usa.jpg">
                        <h2>USA</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#England" data-transition="slide">
                        <img src="img/england.jpg">
                        <h2>England</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#France" data-transition="slide">
                        <img src="img/france.jpg">
                        <h2>France</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#Mexico" data-transition="slide">
                        <img src="img/mexico.jpg">
                        <h2>Mexico</h2>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

I have a few more items listed, so the list is long enough for the user have to scroll down. But when I scroll down, it automatically scrolls back up. I can't even reach the lower items. Any ideas how to fix this?